# Terrible viewport error

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Objects in weight paint mode, and objects not selected when in *Edit/Weight Paint* mode looks like this:

[image]

I've tried changing clipping distance, reinstalling blender and graphics driver, changing viewport AA settings and graphics driver settings and it's still there. The artifacts will also appear in viewport EEVEE render.

System information

- Windows 10 x64 u2004
- Radeon RX6900XT
- Graphics driver version: 21.4.1
- 2D Driver version: 8.1.1.1634
- D3D version: 9.14.10.01494
- OpenGL version: 29.20.11000.14830
- Blender version: 2.83LTS & 2.92

Comment: is it possible that two almost identical objects share the same space?

Comment: It really has this visual effect, but almost all object can cause this error. Only when the object is so simple this won't happen (like the default cube). Even a default icosphere will be painted like in the picture.

Comment: If you are saying this is not a z-fight effect, check bug tracker list ... https://developer.blender.org